# How can I change database data in my code to something else?

Tags: html, php-7.4

I'm trying to change something where if the value from the database is the same as I have put in it automatically changes.

Example

```php
<?php if $building->country is spain change to spanje?>
```

So I want to have that if the value from database is the same as spain I would like to have it changed to spanje. (I cannot change this data in the database since the database is not mine). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean, you've got the basic logic down. Use an `if` statement, like you've shown. What trouble are you running into?

Comment: The problem is that if the value the database gives me it gets converted to the value wich I want wich in this case is spain. So as stated above, if the value = spain I would like to have it changed to spanje.

Comment: @DarkBee how do I do that though?  I could always provide more code, but that's unnecessary in this case.

Comment: which PHP version are you using?

Comment: @DarkBee 7.4.10 I'll include this in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very rudimentary aproach would be to create a *translation map* and test if you've set a translation.
In short you set the database value as the key of the array and the output you want as the value.

With this setup you then can just test if the key (database value) has a (translation) value and output it.

```php
<?php
    $translations = [
        'spain'     => 'spanje'
    ];

    echo $translations[strtolower($building->country)] ?? $building->country;
```

Keep in my mind this is case-sensitive though and a very "bad" way to solve this

Comment: Never mind, this worked. mistyped a character. Thanks!